# FormData boolean field?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data

I need to use booleans within form data. For example:

```
let example = new FormData();
example.append('aBoolean', true);
```

This throws and error as the above 'true' needs to be in string form. Do you know a way I can use booleans within FormData? Alternatively even a way to cast it as a boolean when I get the value by:

```
example.get("aBoolean")
```

Assuming i did store the true as a string in the above example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you cannot set Boolean into `FormData` append method. Only allow datatype are `USVString,Blob`.

Read more about it from mdn documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString

Comment: He states that it is not allowing a boolean. This doesnt really answer his question.

Answer (score 5):

**A simpler solution to me** was to **convert the data to `JSON`** and assign it to one field in the formData:

### Front-end

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({ myBool: false, myNumber: 8 }));
```

### Back-end (nodeJs)

```js
const parsedData = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
console.log(typeof parsedData.myBool === 'boolean'); // => true
console.log(typeof parsedData.myNumber === 'number'); // => true
```

This obviously works with **booleans, null and numbers** types

Answer (score 3):

I believe the second argument of append or set require a string or Blob, not a boolean.

Wherever youre using this I would just use a getter and setter to convert the formData result to boolean. ie:

```
get aBoolean() {
    return this.formDataExample.get('aBoolean') === 'true' ? true : false; 
}

set aBoolean(val: boolean) {
   valAsString = val ? 'true' : 'false';
   this.formDataExample.set('aBoolean', valAsString); 
}
```

Then access aBoolean like it were a normal variable

```
console.log(this.aBoolean);
this.aBoolean = false; // This goes through the setter
```

Using an enum would be better than just 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me, just like **TOPKAT** answers. but in front- end, I use checkbox input which will return boolen value.

**Front-end**

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="draft" />

let example = new FormData();
example.append('aBoolean', true); OR example.append('draft', draft);
```

**Back-end**

```
const draft = JSON.parse(req.body.draft);
console.log(typeof draft === 'boolean'); //true
```